# Chrome v50.0 seems it is zoomed in

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, frontend

I have a responsive site. I added to all pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and in my css I have:

```
html {
    font-size: 93.75%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

I am testing my site in Chrome (50.0.2661.94 (Versão oficial) 64 bits) and my screen size is:

```
console.log(screen.width) // 1920
```

and

```
console.log(window.innerWidth) // 1920
console.log(window.devicePixelRatio) // 1
```

my zoom level is 100% and the website is perfect!

but when I see the same page in my friend's screen it is too big!, his browser is Chrome (50.0.2661.94 (Versão oficial) 64 bits) which it's same as mine. I can see the same way he sees when I zoom in 150%. and he can see the site the same way I do when he zooms out 75%. his screen specs are:

```
console.log(screen.width) // 1360
```

and

```
console.log(window.innerWidth) // 1360
console.log(window.devicePixelRatio) // 1
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: Try this ? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: I've tried it before. it doesn't work.

Comment: Your friend's PC with small screen resolution ?

Comment: yeah. the site looks the same way I see when he zooms out 75% and I see the site the same way it looks in his pc when I zoom in 150%. I tested some other small screen pcs and I got the same result.

Comment: It is happening for me as well, in firefox it seems okay , but in chrome only when i zoom out to 75 percent it seems okay.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee sorry man. I don't remember if i had solved it and if so, what was the solution. Good luck in your journey!